# Method to make revision control program

Tags: php, mysql, version-control

I am currently developing a website in PHP with a MySQL for databases. In this website, I wanted to make a revision control for the content that will be user generated. Similar Wiki/Stack Exchange etc.

What I currently have in mind (not put down on paper or anything) is just have a second table that contains the date, content and the user who submitted the change, but I'm not quite sure if that is the most efficient way to do this.

Also, on top of that, what is the way to view revision changes visually. e.g. someone opens an article, clicks "view changes" and can see who edited it and what was edited. Looking for something similar to SVN's diff program.

Hosh

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff

Comment: MediaWiki is open source software. You can always go see exactly how they do it.

Comment: I don't think I was thinking straight. I had a look at the source and I think I'd be crazy to reinvent the wheel. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who care, I think going to http://pear.horde.org/ and scrolling down to Horde_Text_Diff (or search on the page), should be a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [point-in-time-architecture](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/). I can't tell, how reliable this is as I haven't tried it out yet, but I think it would give you a rough idea.